# Is Newton's 3rd law deducible from postulates of general relativity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity

Since we can derive local conservation of energy and momentum from Einstein's equivalence principle, and Newton's third law seems to to an expression of momentum conservation, is it appropriate to say that we can derive Newton's third law from postulates of GR? Or the 3rd law has to be modified somehow to fit in the framework of relativity?

Comment: Why do you think that a theory of gravity should explain something that applies to other forces as well?

Comment: @Ghoster well GR doesn't even consider gravity as a kind of force, so it's essentially wrong to say "other forces", my motivation is from local conservation of energy and momentum due to equivalence principle.

Comment: @Ghoster wouldn't GR reduce to SR if we exclude gravity? I don't think SR is a theory of gravity too.

Comment: Voting to reopen - the question is perfectly clear. We know that Newton's second law can be derived from GR in the limit of "slow" velocities ($\frac v c << 1$). Can Newton's 3rd law be derived in a similar fashion ? Or is it an underlying assumption of both GR and Newtonian mechanics ?

Answer (score -6):

No, a big no. Newton's third law is about conservation of momentum or we can say that it is stating mechanical equilibirium of a body where its gain in rate of change in momentum equals to loss. So momentum is constant but it doesn't imply that in absence of force a body can be in state of motion or it can continually moving due to inertia but it has achieved constant speed and motion is uniform not accelerated.

While general relativity has principle that universe is ever eventful due to inclusion of time in stating event duration or spacetime length. There is no independence of time so no equilibirium, also due to scalar product to define length there is non-linearity.

Comment: I just searched for more materials on the topic, answers like this [link](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/ask/listing/19577) seems to imply that Newton's third law is compatible with GR. What confused me at the beginning is that Einstein's equivalence principle implies local conservation of energy and momentum, and Newton's third also has a deep relation with conservation, so I wander if the local conservation is enough to imply Newton's third law. Thanks all the same.